# How to check if loop is closed using turf booleanValid in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, geometry, turfjs

I use TypeScript and currently I wish to validate a Geometry object.
I use `booleanValid` from turf package to ensure that the object is valid.

```
const isGeometryValid: boolean = booleanValid(geometry as unknown as Geometry);
```

After testing I found out that the `booleanValid` only checks the Right-Hand Rule and doesn't check if the loop is closed.
The following array returned true even though the loop is not closed just because it satisfies the Right-Hand Rule:

```
[ [ [0,0], [10,0], [10,10], [0,10], [0,8] ] ]
```

I need a way to check all the validations for Geometry and not just one or some of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`booleanValid` is unstable in its current state and I was advised by a collaborator to find an alternative for using turf for validating geometry objects.

> I personally would say in it's current state not to rely on
> booleanValid for comprehensive GeoJSON validation. You could
> potentially look at packages such as
> https://github.com/placemark/check-geojson and
> https://github.com/mapbox/geojsonhint which may offer similar
> alternatives depending on your requirements.